# Python unicode error. UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4e3a'

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

So, I have this code to fetch JSON string from `url`

```
url = 'http://....'
response = urllib2.urlopen(rul)
string = response.read()
data = json.loads(string)

for x in data: 
    print x['foo']
```

The problem is `x['foo']`, if tried to print it as seen above, I get this error.

> Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\xBA Co...' for column 'description' at row 1

If I use `x['foo'].decode("utf-8")` I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4e3a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

If I try, `encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`
Then I get this error.

> x['foo'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Read http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x['foo'].decode("utf-8")` resulting in `UnicodeEncodeError` means that `x['foo']` is of type `unicode`. [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) takes a `str` type and translates it to `unicode` type. Python 2 is trying to be helpful here and attempts to implicitly convert your `unicode` to `str` so that you can call `decode` on it. It does this with `sys.defaultencoding`, which is `ascii`, which can't encode all of Unicode, hence the exception.

The solution here is to remove the `decode` call - the value is already `unicode`.

Read Ned Batchelder's presentation -  [Pragmatic Unicode](http://bit.ly/unipain) - it will greatly enhance your understanding of this and help prevent similar errors in the future.

It's worth noting here that everything returned by `json.load` will be `unicode` and not `str`.

---

Addressing the new question after edits:

When you `print`, you need bytes - unicode is an abstract concept. You need a mapping from the abstract unicode string into bytes - in python terms, you must convert your `unicode` object to `str`. You can do this be calling `encode` with an encoding that tells it how to translate from the abstract string into concrete bytes. Generally you want to use the utf-8 encoding.

This should work:

```
print x['foo'].encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, for the link. I'll take a look at it, but right now, it would be nice to have an answer as I am sure, I am getting errors even while removing `decode`. All the other lists in the array are fine, but sometimes the `x['foo']` contains emojis asiic characters, and that is causing the issue

Comment: This answers the question you posted; if you're getting other errors in your app it's because you're still making the same mistake (mixing up unicode and str types). Reading the link presents some very in-depth explanation and guidance on preventing it from happening at all

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought that would do it, but I am getting `Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\xBA Co...' for column 'foo' at row 1` using as you suggested `x['foo'].encode('utf-8')`. Do I really need to `import` some library for the encoding to work?

Comment: @arbi-g11324115 Is `print` given you that error or something else? I'd open a new question with that specifically, because it sounds like you're using some database library that isn't handling unicode well. Off the top of my head, because you mentioned emoji, might you be running on a somewhat old version of mysql? Some emoji are new to the unicode standard, and older versions of mysql don't support it yet

Comment: Maybe that's it. I really can't tell. I am using `mysql 5.4` Here is how I am setting the unicode `conn = MySQLdb.connect("****","root","****","****")
conn.set_character_set('utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')`

Comment: @arbi-g11324115 5.4 is old. It's almost certainly your problem. It only supports unicode characters that were defined when it was made. Since it was made, new characters were defined - it doesn't know how to handle them. Open a new question.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. There is a 90 minute cap in SO, so I can't post another question unless after 25 minutes.

Comment: Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994772/mariadb-python-issues-with-emoji-characters

Comment: @arbi-g11324115: don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script i.e., print Unicode directly. Drop `.encode('utf-8')`: `print x['foo']` -- otherwise you may get mojibake. If `print  u'\u4e3a'` fails then don't touch your script,  configure your environment instead (typically, it is enough to set non-ascii locale on Unix (LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL envvars), install `win-unicode-console` to print Unicode in Windows console, or force I/O encoding if the output is redirected using `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's not good advice for anything but printing to console. Network traffic will have a known encoding, databases will too. Relying on python2's implicit type coercion is an error-prone pattern.

Comment: @Daenyth: Obviously, OP uses `print` for debug output to console. Who uses `print` to output to a network or database? (if you do (in a shell pipeline) then set `PYTHONIOENCODING` outside your script)

Comment: ponder, what happens in Python 3 and why if you try to print text as bytes using the `print` function.