# MariaDB / Python issues with emoji characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mysql-python, mariadb

I have a string in `x['foo']`, sometimes it's a normal string, other times it is a emoji or text art ..

So, I am getting this error in trying to submit the content into database.

> Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xB8\xBA Co...' for column 'description' at row 1

If I use `x['foo'].decode("utf-8")` I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4e3a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

If I try, `encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`
Then I get this error.

> x['foo'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

I am using **MariaDB 5.5.44** and **Python 2.7.5**

I am initializing my database as

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","")
conn.set_character_set('utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

Comment: As mentioned in your other post, `x['foo']` is `unicode`, not a `string`, so calling `decode` doesn't make sense. The `NoneType` error is strange. do `print repr(x['foo'])`

Comment: Note the *encode* error when decoding. You already have Unicode, no need to decode that. Python tries to *encode* first so it can decode for you.

Comment: MariaDB / MySQL UTF-8 doesn't support Emoji. Use the newer [utf8mb4 codec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) instead, which supports the full Unicode range.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, I will just modify the unicode to `utf8mb4` in `cursor.execute()` or do I need to install additional python library?

Comment: You need to adjust the `SET *` queries to use `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8`.